# How to pass data from a html page to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages:

- choose.html
- create.html

In the **choose.html** I can choose an entry from a listview. I can click on such entries in the listview and I want to pass the **ID** of that entry so that I can use the **ID** on the html page **create.html**.

**ID** is a number.

I have done:

When I clicked on an entry, I get the ID:

```
function postID(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

This functions so far.

Then I tried this code with a GET on the create.html:

POST:

```
function postID(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "create.html",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: id,
        success: function () {
            document.location.href = "create.html";
        },
        error: function (jqXhr) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

GET:

```
try {
    $.get("chooseAddress.html", function (id) {
        alert(id);
    });
} 
    catch (e) {
        alert();
}
```

But nothing happens. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you simply use `queryString`? Read [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: use a cookie or add a query to the url which you can then read out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many work for so simple problem. Use a hidden field or use a Session variable.

Comment: I don't want to use PHP.

Comment: The process is same. Now you can use any language.

Comment: Suggestions should be mentioned in a comment. 
He tagged the question properly.

Comment: Session variables are not available in HTML, unless you use a server side scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

Use create a hidden field and give value as your Id.
 
`<form action='create.html'>
<input type='hidden' value='id'>
</form>`